# How to stop "permission denied" app toasts after denying permissions?

Tags: permissions, toast-notifications

I often like to deny app permissions that I think the app does not need but yet they keep requesting for the permissions even after Denying, resulting in lot of toasts `[package name] has been denied [permission name] permission`.

How do I permanently suppress these toasts?

I am using android **Kitkat**.

Comment: How do you deny? Using some app? Please provide more details like android version etc.

Comment: I'm in Android KitKat and they the security option which if you turn on well give you control over all applications request for various privileges

Comment: Your best and most permanent solution, if you disagree with the permissions requested by the developer, is to drop the app, give in, or re-write the app yourself to your own restrictive standards.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your primary aim is to turn off some permissions. So I will form my answer to that direction.

***If you are rooted:***

**Choice 1:** Since you are referring to toasts, there is a way to turn them off using the xposed module [Untoaster](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-untoaster-xposed-t2624523). I wish I could tell you how to use that, but I currently cant use xposed due to compatibility issues. SO this, you may have to test and figure out your self.

**Choice 2:** You can also try using [lucky patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download/). It can disable permissions. To do this, open lucky patcher and grant it root rights. Then browse to app/package name whose permissions you want to block and tap on it. Then select the option `Edit Permissions` and tap on permissions to enable/disable them. Be careful though, you may end up messing up the app.

***If you are not rooted:***

In this case, we will modify app permissions to the core. We will edit a minor code/xml so app doesn't even know of those permissions. *Yes, it is a very DIRTY trick. There are consequences.*

- Firstly, download [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). Refer [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1891686) guide on how to use (you will be using the compiling/decompiling and signing features).
- Firstly, get the app's apk. You can either use some app backup program or use [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en). If you decide to go with terminal emulator, open it and run these commands:

`mkdir /sdcard/apps123`

`cp /data/app/*.apk /sdcard/apps123`

This will copy all the APK files installed by you inside `apps123`folder in your internal sdcard.

- After you have got the apk and decompiled it, go to `apktoolDirectory/projects/[package name you decompiled]` folder and open AndroidManifest.xml with some editor ([Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.8.2.html) recommended.
- After you have opened the file, look for permission lines. They will have the format:

(In this case, its permission to write internal storage).

- Delete out lines corresponding to permissions you do not want. All permissions are defined at beginning of xml so you dont need to explore the whole manifest.
- After you are done, compile app again and sign it. Put it to phone and install.

------> You can also have a look at this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to see what each permission does.

NOTE: There is also an [android version of APKTool](https://code.google.com/p/apktool/). You can install and use it in phone itself. Its much more easier to use but takes longer time to complete tasks.

----> This method wont give you toast notifications like now.

**Drawbacks of this method:**

- You wont be able to update app from play store anymore.
- Whenever app tries to access that feature whose permission is missing, it will cause a security exception and app is likely to crash unless developer has handled it (which they normally dont).

Comment: +1, that Untoaster worked, although it is definitely not friendly to anyone who is not familiar with the word regex. Thanks again.