# How can i disable android permission manager notification?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, permissions

I have an android 4.4.2 device and permission manager app enabled.

I have facebook messenger installed for example and i deny it permission to read my sms or phone contacts.

It works, but keeps displaying "Messenger is denied " in the center bottom lower screen for ages. Sometimes i need to reboot my device to make it go away.

*absolutely annoying*

Comment: That's called a toast. Permissions manager is part of Android (`android`) and you can't do anything about it without root access. See if there is an option to not show toast/notifications, in your permission manager app.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I had no idea it's called like that. Will search google on toasts and whatnot but my device is rooted. any advice on how i can do something about it given that it's rooted ?

Comment: I can give you the way, but as I said, it is part of Android (`android`). It's take or leave approach. There is no compromise. My solution would make you end up with no USB connected notification, no low storage notification, may be many more native notifications that you will not be able to see. Do you still want the solution?

Comment: i think i can adapt it or something. so please tell.

Comment: Things are different in my case. Sorry I mixed things up with my Lollipop. I need some clarification. Do you see a notification in the notification bar about Permission manager? Or do you know the app responsible for that toast. I see that in my Android 4.4.2 the relevant app is named "Permissions Control"  whose [package name](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/96277) is `com.mediatek.security`. What's the name in your case?

Comment: See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/111086/96277). It lead me to [Untoaster](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-untoaster-xposed-t2624523) app (requires Xposed Framework). Once you're done installing it, you have to use a regex pattern. For example, if you choose com.mediatek.security as app or `all` then then the pattern would be `[a-zA-Z]+ is denied`. You've to tweak it until the toasts are stopped coming.

Answer (score 2):

"Toasts" are implemented in an app's java programming, so that needs to be modified in some way, assuming the app doesn't give you the option to configure toasts. The following assumes you're rooted.

**The easy way:** Use Xposed. There are many modules available to block all toasts, block toasts for a specific app, or even customize toasts, e.g. [EnhancedToast](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-enhancedtoast-t2625433) and [UnToaster Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-untoaster-xposed-t2624523). Xposed supports Android 2.2(Froyo) and up, with increasing support for 5.0+(Lollipop). If your Android is bootloader locked, aka no TWRP/CWM recovery, you can see if your device can run [FlashFire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/paid-software/flashfire-t3075433) to install Xposed. **Note:** To use Xposed modules on an app, it needs to be deodexed, e.g. data apps, apps you download from the Play Store are deodexed.

**The hard way:** You can usually decompile an app into smali code, edit the smali code to disable toasts, and then recompile the app. Without smali modification, this process is known as deodexing. If you're interested, check out this Lollipop compatible [deodexing guide](https://github.com/bmc08gt/scripts/tree/master/deodex-lollipop) for decompiling an app's java code, and this [smali code editing guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2193735) to learn how to edit smali code.